# How do you output the contents of an .eml file [ Not including all of its metadata ] to the commandline in plaintext?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, email, mail, mutt

I can do this:

```
cat foobar.eml
```

```
Delivered-To: anonymous@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a4a:6c09:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id q9-v6csp1498994ooc;
        Thu, 23 Aug 2018 10:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ANB0VdbsRmqaaUs41HCS0zliF29KjnrQqZE+srtTakEZc+PVSCUEFl8HpZfCTXRfwolCrpwIuZ3i
X-Received: by 2002:a37:61ca:: with SMTP id v193-v6mr21368476qkb.307.1535043637258;
        Thu, 23 Aug 2018 10:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1535043637; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=nNhTOOwiVbxnGokbmAWg9fp4aInzO+Q7mPC5Nzu/1gfsjq5y4JX0EDsBicLrMYCSX7
         8BifYeDYFi646D3rFxP6eja4bd2bMtWOdGDNe5R1SK2yqREU66ivi8vbnkfsuT3c+0BW
         +CM5ByXWdAHl7ySrPySaxhFNnj+/oT/TC3lss83g4KO3dslvQFmx2uTgXJwuOAde23As
         22jg6F2s9nG5uEKk02tfZ99U8Boz5AWUtpe+AmjudMP/YVhUNep8uL+9sC4WSHkPZVwG
         eDlUTgdpXE7CKOrEMfbMw/vD5elekSNdKAt92q2ooXMYZxYZC4zuMjjAkfLUAvT/0ZsV
         WXng==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=thread-index:thread-topic:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version
         :subject:message-id:cc:to:from:date:dkim-signature
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=kaeeCo6FPQb2D167BEzpileq9J1mjS9umYUnnWzC4fg=;
        b=HlvSPoSofaPVe2bGCcCBz2WD5iOGjyF9uNDN9bDXcqnEN/xUBgVgFSuVrLfAi0FkgH
         yChEaIu7md/1CufOpaTfFaQHIFB8x8WP4MIcu2SDSJ5dyVGL6gTTLnTmGBU2svJRw41I
         qZMDxL62KJxzmZ1sYMyOG6CiKiXA/PqH3rMy9omVTLEgQMWAJQWdHaqn2+82V7XrMJMp
         P7wZMzNKyg1QU7dnKATftQEHzR4xBvfsqSOuvdQeYQZB+xSewrY/rVw2hhtuzqKiL+s+
         Pfa6XdiP8mzGO3yHUBOfMolC1odvTJw0OhWnVS0bMx81E2PmUkxmi4MtAu4HrwfEvAYK
         VcEQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass (test mode) header.i=@telus.net header.s=neo header.b="l6Q+/5CE";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ms@telus.net designates 209.171.16.92 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=ms@telus.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=telus.net
Return-Path: <ms@telus.net>
Received: from cmta19.telus.net (cmta19.telus.net. [209.171.16.92])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id p22-v6si4646092qtn.292.2018.08.23.10.00.36
        for <anonymous@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Thu, 23 Aug 2018 10:00:37 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ms@telus.net designates 209.171.16.92 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.171.16.92;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass (test mode) header.i=@telus.net header.s=neo header.b="l6Q+/5CE";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ms@telus.net designates 209.171.16.92 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=ms@telus.net;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=telus.net
Received: from mtlp000024.email.telus.net ([172.20.100.250])
        by cmsmtp with SMTP
        id ssxyfjNXWwgrmssxyfNVR7; Thu, 23 Aug 2018 11:00:14 -0600
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=telus.net; s=neo;
        t=1535043636; bh=kaeeCo6FPQb2D167BEzpileq9J1mjS9umYUnnWzC4fg=;
        h=Date:From:To:Cc:Subject;
        b=l6Q+/5CElxHMO0AAM94M3WgcPJOzxPDYuDtmgJm5tv/sfSaC1M4du8YDwiesmYVSe
         5addUv9uuzozrqXIr4VRjEzeghy+mGXXz+37xtTGDjMiOCTfC2XQQiwGMN4xnxIksE
         x7ZikbTK92HCCw9YNEtPU2Jx+0A2pbkE1IJZLkNMm4ZbfKSpykcZxMezNrd2jqbhqr
         M0YWVFGK4ssyY90SAA1bUrs2TbR6/aiVx+MVTfKMRMDcgWxZkQNH8hi3gMFB6qo1Yj
         vPPjig8L9I9ittJzJhua0hQ5qoiczV7EuuIUmj632ELBMqNpxjZ+eoTfkopqdVrMm0
         Re8l6PofcDSXw==
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.3 cv=D4zz1cZj c=1 sm=1 tr=0
 a=4bd358MHcbnBkp+IcMzszA==:117 a=FKkrIqjQGGEA:10 a=c4iJmxt-oRkA:10
 a=IkcTkHD0fZMA:10 a=3-ypyTq862YA:10 a=CkcOa_KSredVPgaKXFsA:9
 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 a=IeVV3oy9AQTmNaZTXIJc:22 a=HH7FIXwXL_sUf1zzYxQd:22
Date: Thu, 23 Aug 2018 11:00:14 -0600 (MDT)
From: Mark Shuttleworth <ms@telus.net>
To: Anon Nymous <anonymous@gmail.com>
Cc: anon <anon@linux.com>
Message-ID: <1128236357.158124045.1535043614388.JavaMail.zimbra@mailid.telus.net>
Subject: 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Originating-IP: [64.141.83.200]
X-Mailer: Zimbra 8.6.0_GA_1211 (ZimbraWebClient - GC68 (Win)/8.6.0_GA_1211)
Thread-Topic: 
Thread-Index: 4C/VEhjjLopwgDRppzCAI1WxFuTADQ==
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4wfF577AQm5rPY75XDCo9d38reUiFqLFb/V9KgB3keLWlmmFpw2co7BOzQYtp5JuUmW5KgSZEkkAoLx3Kajb2rnH/ukB+ZyaxSNRovQpQtIdvCEc64bWTn
 QPxxSAPPTke/wftwqJmPm+qEqdkT/YAKDNLQGfl+1L/ecGDVwYnEYCWk1ufP241E4p2K5K7UVrE6zjBD/pQUaVfsYJC8S/H69RoTieoorspDGPT2a+nTSJtK



HI Anon
How are you doing?

I am at the Ubuntu library today.
```

When all I want is:

```
HI Anon
How are you doing?

I am at the Ubuntu library today.
```

I have tried looking at mutt, mail, mailx, but I can't find a way to just output to commandline. Opening a TUI also will not work, because I need to concatenate the messages of ~100 emails.

Regarding `munpack -t foobar.eml`

> `Did not find anything to unpack from foobar.eml`

Thanks.

Comment: you can install `mpack`, then run `munpack -t foobar.eml` and `cat part1`.

Comment: I believe the headers are separated from the mail body simply by two newline characters. You could write a script that discards everything before the `\n\n` pattern. However, you would still need to deal with HTML mail.

Comment: @pLumo Unfortunately that does not work. It gives an error: `Did not find anything to unpack from foobar.eml`.

Comment: Maybe you can try a Python library like https://eml-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I think your .eml file is not valid. I tried with something exported from Thunderbird and it worked perfectly. With your .eml from your Q I get the same error.

Comment: @pLumo These too were exported from Thunderbird. Its all right though, I ended up printing the emails as PDF's instead, and concatenated them under libreoffice draw. I also made an app for regex parsing, but I did not end up using it because the parsing becomes complex when dealing with multipart emails.